# Why $V$ has has an orthonormal eigenbasis$\{e_i\}$ and $AA^*e_i=\lambda_i^2e_i$, where $\lambda_i\geq0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For any $A\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{C}) $, why linear space $V$ has an orthonormal  eigenbasis$\{e_i\}$ and $AA^*e_i=\lambda_i^2e_i$, where $\lambda_i\geq0$?

Comment: This is just the Spectral Theorem for Hermitian matrices..

Comment: @GitGud, thanks. I think the basis relate to the space $V$

Comment: What is space $V$?

Comment: @PavelJiranek arbitrary linear space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that $AA^*$ is self-adjoint since
$$(AA^*)^* = A^{**}A^* = AA^*$$
So you can apply the [Spectral Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Hermitian_maps_and_Hermitian_matrices) to get an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $\{e_i\}$ and corresponding *real* eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}$. To see that they are non-negative note that we have
$$\lambda_i \langle e_i, e_i \rangle = \langle AA^*e_i, e_i \rangle = \langle A^*e_i, A^*e_i \rangle \geq 0 $$
and hence $\lambda_i \geq 0$.

Note also $V$ can't be an arbitrary linear space; it must at least have an inner product if we want to speak of $A^*$ or of orthonormal bases.